# Adding Gravatar to rss feed

Tags: rss, gravatar

So I have a mailchimp email that goes out and shows the latest posts that have been made on the site. The users on the site all have gravatars and I want to include that in the rss feed so that I can point the mailchimp image reader to them.

I have tried using snippets like:

```
<?php echo get_avatar( get_current_user_id(), 48 ); ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo get_avatar( get_author_email(), 48 ); ?>
```

and adding that to the rss template in /wp_includes (I would love to do it in functions.php but honestly I just want it to work for this one site so I don't care how I get it done).

It's curious because when I do searches I can only find people trying to figure out how to remove it instead of insert it... I am at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

The point is, that the format have no tags for a image to a user. You must use a other tag to inlcude the avatar of a author, not the author tag. The author tag is only for a string, not markkup or images. But you can add content ot the desciption and this is easy on the filter [`the_content_feed`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content_feed).

A small example, there add content to this part in the feed.

```
add_filter( 'the_content_feed', 'fb_plugin_function_name' );
/**
* @param  $content Content of post
* @return string
*/
function fb_plugin_function_name( $content ) {

   $content .= 'Total ' . str_word_count( $content ) . ' words';
   return $content;
}
```

Comment: Not entirely following what you are suggesting.

I found this snippet: 

`/ Put post thumbnails into rss feed
function wpfme_feed_post_thumbnail($content) {
 global $post;
 if(has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
  $content = '' . $content;
 }
 return $content;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'wpfme_feed_post_thumbnail');
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'wpfme_feed_post_thumbnail');`

do you know how I could modify this for a gravatar post?

Comment: yes, but the thumbnail have a other job. It is a enhancement for the post content, the avatar is a identify for a auther. A feed is xml, a semantic markup and each tag have a description from the definition. Your code is like the same as my example inside the answer. But I will write abiut the topic, there is fine, that you think about the job of the tag inside the xml of feed. You can add a avatar to the content, but it have no semantic importance.